# Trying to apply the pattern from sean parent's talk "inheritance is the base class of evil"

Tags: c++

https://ideone.com/1Pkxwe

I'm trying to make a for comprehension in c++. I want to construct a `For` instance out of some number of other iterable containers. Later I'll pass a function and the `For` will call the function on it's contents.

I haven't gotten past the heterogeneous vector yet but I'm imagining that

```
void f(int i, char c) {
    cout << i << " " << c << endl;
}
For(1,2)('a','b').yield(f);
```

will print

```
1 a
1 b
2 a
2 b
```

The above is just pseudo code... This is what I have so far. I'm borrowing heavily from Sean Parents talk and that source may be found here.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2012/master/fri/value_semantics/value_semantics.cpp

The Model::print doesn't see the Object::print functions and I don't understand why. It seems similar to that linked source code and it works there...

error output from ideone

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Object::Model<T>::print() [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
prog.cpp:58:5:   required from here
prog.cpp:26:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘Object::Model<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::print(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’
                 print(data);
                 ~~~~~^~~~~~
prog.cpp:25:18: note: candidate: void Object::Model<T>::print() [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
             void print() {
                  ^~~~~
prog.cpp:25:18: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Object::Model<T>::print() [with T = int]’:
prog.cpp:58:5:   required from here
prog.cpp:26:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘Object::Model<int>::print(int&)’
                 print(data);
                 ~~~~~^~~~~~
prog.cpp:25:18: note: candidate: void Object::Model<T>::print() [with T = int]
             void print() {
                  ^~~~~
prog.cpp:25:18: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

and the code

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Object {
    template <typename T>
    Object(T t) : model(new Model<T>(t)) {
        cout << "construct object from T" << endl;
    }
    friend void print(string str) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    friend void print(int i) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    struct Concept {
        virtual void print() =0;
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct Model : Concept {
        Model(T t) : data(t) {}
        void print() {
            print(data);
        }
        T data;
    };
    Concept *model;
};

struct For {
    For() {
        cout << "default construct For" << endl;
    }
    For(Object o) {
        cout << "construct For from object and push back" << endl;
        objects.push_back(o);
    }
    For operator()(Object o) {
        cout << "push back object" << endl;
        objects.push_back(o);
        return *this;
    }
    void print() {
        for(auto o : objects) {
            o.model->print();
        }
    };
    vector<Object> objects;
};

int main() {
    auto heterogeneous = For(1)(string("hello"));
    function<void(int)> f = [](int i)->void{ cout << i << endl; };
    heterogeneous.print();
}
```

A million thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few changes to make it compile.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void print(T&&);      // <- so that Object::Model knows what you want.

struct Object {
    template <typename T>
    Object(T t) : model(new Model<T>(t)) {
        cout << "construct object from T" << endl;
    }
    friend void print(string str) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    friend void print(int i) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    struct Concept {
        virtual ~Concept() = default;   // <- you MUST have a virtual dtor
        virtual void print() =0;
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct Model : Concept {
        Model(T t) : data(t) {}
        void print() {
            ::print(data);   // <-- the :: because Model::print hid what you wanted to call
        }
        T data;
    };
    Concept *model;
};


struct For {   // I don't recall this from Sean's talk.  I don't think it 
               // works as intended.
    For() {
        cout << "default construct For" << endl;
    }
    For(Object o) {
        cout << "construct For from object and push back" << endl;
        objects.push_back(o);
    }
    For operator()(Object o) {
        cout << "push back object" << endl;
        objects.push_back(o);
        return *this;
    }
    void print() {
        for(auto o : objects) {
            o.model->print();
        }
    };
    vector<Object> objects;
};

// print functions for your types.

void print(const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << s << "\n";
}

void print(const int& i)
{
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}

int main() {
    auto heterogeneous = For(1)(string("hello"));  // this adds [1,"hello"] to the model
                                                   // is this what you want?
    //function<void(int)> f = [](int i)->void{ cout << i << endl; };
    heterogeneous.print();
}
```

In Sean's talk, what is your Object class was the actual document class, and that's where the vector<> lived. From what I understand, your for class should be a vector of documents, but it cannot do this as written.

Comment: `=delete` the "base" print to get earlier and better error messages when you fail to adl-define a print overload.  Also concept need virtual dtor.

Comment: You're right.  Didn't catch the virtual dtor <face palm>...  Adding...  But =delete only works on functions that can be implicit

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "can be implicit".  The above code with `=delete` should work, and I am unaware of when it shoildn't.

Comment: You could use `virtual type func() =delete` in a derived class, but not for the definition of a pure virtual class.  tried on gcc with example above just now, on compiler explorer

Comment: No `template <typename T> void print(T&&)=delete;`.  Not `virtual` base, just the "base" one that exists so `::print(data)` in `Model` finds a symbol.  As written above you get a linker error; add `=delete` and you get a compile time error pointing at `Model<T>::print`.  Also using `::print` blocks ADL there, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh... _that_ print....   Just tried it, gcc 7.2 `gcc -std=c++1y -O3`  doesn't like it either.

Comment: ::print() doesn't block adl.  The function print() was hidden by the function Model::print.  Calling a free function at that point is part of the pattern.  The idea if to allow aggregation of objects that do not derive from Concept, like std::string, or int in the example above, or any kind of object actually.  To allow a `class AnyKindOfObject` to be added to the document, the user must define a free function `void print(const AnyKindOfObject&)` to provide the functionality.  The pattern is known as "runtime polymorphism"

Comment: `namespace foo { struct bar { friend void print(bar) { std::cout << "bar\n"; }};}` try  making a `foo::bar` model.

Comment: The OP would have to rename Model::print.  and even then, the pattern _requires_ the free functions to be in a namespace that's implicitely available.  That would be the same namespace as the forward definition of `template<> print()`.

Comment: Yes, the model `print` should be renamed (it is an internal implementation detail), but no, ADL will look in namespaces related to passed types of you do not block it by using explicit namespace scope operations on the call.  That is an important part of this pattern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152972/discussion-between-michael-roy-and-yakk).

Comment: https://ideone.com/u5YD38

Thank you @Michael Roy. I now have two free functions that the model can call for printing ints and strings. That is exactly what I was hoping to get as an answer.


 I went ahead and renamed Model::print to Model::apply anyway. I didn't even think of that as a solution until you pointed it out.


 This isn't working as a forward declaration so I moved the free print functions to the top. I also removed the friend functions inside the Object class.


`template <typename T>
void print(T&&);      // <- so that Object::Model knows what you want.`

Comment: I think that my Object class serves the same purpose as Parent's object_t class. I'm not using a `vector<copy_on_write<object_t>>` instead I just have a `vector<object_t>` that I'm pushing on to. His copy_on_write class has an object_t instance inside of it and manually tracks the reference count. Instead of a vector of reference-counted-copy-on-write things I just have my Object thing.
 
 The next step for me to make this work as in the psuedo-code at the top is to be able to pass in a function to a `For::yield(function<()> f)` member function and have f called on Object::Model::data.

Comment: Maybe yield is not a good name for it, since it means 'let pass'. `apply() const`, `transform()` or `visit()` member functions may be more appropriate names... But hey, it's your code. The copy-on-write vector thing was added for the undo functionality, wasn't it?  That is the most efficient undo stack I've ever seen.

Comment: Haha, yea. I'm bad at naming things. Yea, it is an efficient undo stack.

\r\n 
    I'm trying to make what's available here https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension and here https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

I have a lot of food for thought at the moment. I hope I can figure it out but I might have to come back here. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

So, I took a stab at your overall problem.

The below code compiles.  It copies things a bit much (I got lazy), but it supports doing a `For` cross-product with a simple `For(a,b,c)(1,2,3)` generating `((a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(b,1),(b,2),(b,3),(c,1),(c,2),(c,3))`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


// Default print; stream to cout:
template <typename T>
void print(T const& t){ std::cout << t <<"\n"; }

// Functional-style loops:
struct Object;
// a loop-body is a "sink" of Objects.  In C++, it is the part after the control flow, the code
// that gets run each iteration.
using Body=std::function<void(Object)>;
// a loop is a "sink" of loop-bodies.  Read this as "loop over the contents of an Object, doing Body"
using Loop=std::function<void(Body)>;

// default foreach: return a loop that just visits yourself:
template <typename T>
Loop foreach(T const& t) {
  return [t](Body body){ body(t); };
}

// custom printing:
inline void print(std::string const& str) {
  std::cout << "\"" << str  <<"\"" << std::endl;
}
inline void print(int i) {
  std::cout << "Integer: "<< i << std::endl;
}
// such custom prints can go here, or in the namespace of the type.

// Objects are actually smart pointers to type-erased data:
struct Object {
  template <typename T>
  Object(T t) : model(std::make_shared<Model<T>>(std::forward<T>(t))) {
  //  std::cout << "construct object from T" << std::endl;
  }

  friend void print(Object o){
    o.model->do_print();
  }
  friend Loop foreach(Object o){
    return o.model->do_foreach();
  }
  struct Concept {
    virtual void do_print() =0;
    virtual Loop do_foreach() = 0;
    // no dtor, as shared ptr handles that
  };

  template <typename T>
  struct Model final : Concept {
    Model(T t) : data(std::forward<T>(t)) {}
    void do_print() override {
      print(data); 
    }
    Loop do_foreach( ) override {
      return foreach(data);
    }
    T data;
  };
  std::shared_ptr<Concept> model;
};


struct For {
  For() {}
  template<class...Ts>
  For(Ts const&...ts):
    objects({ts...})
  {}
  // given an Object o, return that object's contents
  // in a For.
  static For box(Object o) {
    For tmp;
    foreach(o)([&tmp](Object o){ tmp+=o; });
    return tmp;
  }
  For(For const&)=default;
  For& operator+=(Object o){ objects.push_back(o); return *this; }
  For operator+(Object o) const { For tmp=*this; tmp+= o; return tmp; }
  For operator*(For rhs)const{
    For tmp;
    for( auto o1 : objects )
      for( auto o2 : rhs.objects )
      {
        tmp += box(o1) + o2;
      }
    return tmp;
  }
  For& operator*=(For rhs){
    *this = *this*rhs;
    return *this;
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  For operator()(Ts const&... ts) {
    *this *= For(ts...);
    return *this;
  }
  friend Loop foreach(For const& f){
    return [f](Body body){
      for(auto o : f.objects) {
        body(o);
      }
    };
  }

  friend void print(For f) {
    std::cout << "{";
    for(auto o : f.objects) {
      print(o);
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
  };
  std::vector<Object> objects;
};
```

Test code:

```
int main() {
  auto a = For(std::string("hello"),42)(1,-1);
  auto b = a;
  b('a','b','c');
  std::cout <<"a:\n";
  print(a);
  std::cout <<"b:\n";
  print(b);
}
```

Comment: This is so amazing, thank you so much! I'm still working on understanding it but I wanted to acknowledge and thank you before the day is over. You two are just the best!